# How to get rid of "Parse error in pattern" error in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble with some haskell code. Namely a function checksum
which is meant to check whether the sum of a list of Integers is equal to the Integer argument tot.

There is something wrong with the syntax because I keep getting:

```
Main.hs:11:1: Parse error in pattern: checksum
```

And the module isn't loaded.

```
checksum :: ([Int], Int) -> (Bool, Int)

checksum [x] tot
    | x == tot        = (True, tot)
    | otherwise       = (False, tot)

checksum x:xs tot = checksum xs tot-x`
```

Comment: What's line 11?

Comment: `checksum (x:xs) tot` and also see http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions

Comment: May I ask why you are using a tuple in the first argument?  Your function definitions seem to want `checksum :: [Int] -> Int -> (Bool, Int)`

Comment: Proposal (not related to your error): make your base case be `[]` instead of `[x]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a number of corrections to make this work.  I am going on the assumption that your type annotation is correct.

```
checksum :: ([Int], Int) -> (Bool, Int)

checksum ([x], tot) -- make argument a single tuple
    | x == tot        = (True, tot)
    | otherwise       = (False, tot)

checksum ((x:xs), tot) = checksum (xs, tot-x) -- group list; make argument and result a tuple.
-- removed extraneous back-tick at the end of the last line.
```

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, function application has a higher associative strength than any other operation.

So, the pattern `checksum x:xs tot` is parsed as `(checksum x):(xs tot)`, which doesn't make any sense as a pattern, and causes a parse error.  Specifically, patterns don't allow function applications, such as `(checksum x)`, except for defining functions at the top level.

As the comment says, you should parenthesize it as `checksum (x:xs) tot` so it will parse as you expect, defining `checksum` at the top level.